# gtkmm get size of widget

Tags: c++, widget, gtkmm

I simply want to know which size a widget has. I need this info to set a ScrolledWindow to a maximum size if the size of the widget is bigger than the screen.

But all functions I know give a constant value of 1.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <gtkmm.h>
#include <gtkmm/window.h>

class ExampleWindow: public Gtk::Window
{
    Gtk::Button button;
    public:
    ExampleWindow(): button("Hallo")
    {
        add(button);
        GetSize();
    }

    void GetSize()
    {
        std::cout << button.get_width() << " " << button.get_height() << std::endl;
        std::cout << button.get_allocated_width() << " " << button.get_allocated_height() << std::endl;
    }
};


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Gtk::Main kit(argc, argv);

    ExampleWindow window;

    window.GetSize();
    window.show_all_children();
    window.GetSize();
    Gtk::Main::run(window);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A side note, if useful to you: `#include<gtkmm.h>` already takes care of the `#include<gtkmm/window.h>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks a lot like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396280/unable-to-get-height-width-of-a-widget-gtkmm).

Basically it says that before the `get_height()` and `get_width()` methods return meaningful values, the widget must be *realized*. Since you are calling these (through your `GetSize()` wrapper) inside the window constructor, it (the button inside the window) might not yet be realized, hence the wrong values.

---

**BONUS**

According to [this ticket](https://blogs.gnome.org/jnelson/2010/10/13/those-realize-map-widget-signals/):

> Realize means to create the GDK resources for a widget. i.e. to
>   instantiate the widget on the display.

Also, to clarify the meaning of the word *realize*, see [this](https://blogs.gnome.org/jnelson/2010/10/13/those-realize-map-widget-signals/). The author seems to have done some interesting research on the subject to clarify the documentation.